# Mars Editor works in the command line, but not on double click

Tags: java, jar

Not sure if this is right place to ask, but I recently had to reinstall Windows 10 on my laptop along with all my other programs that I had previously. One them was Mars editor for MIPS. I could not get to run by double clicking it. A message box would pop up with this error.

[image]

But when I go into command prompt and cd in to the folder where this is store and type the command `java -jar Mars.jar` the editor opens just fine. I tried deleting and uninstalling both Mars and Java and then reinstalling them, but that didn't change anything. [This is the page](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/download.htm) where the download page for Java is attached and download for the Mars editor, so I know I'm downloading the right things.

Anyone else have this same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't really the answer I was hoping for, but this works none the less.

**Create a batch file with the following**

```
@echo OFF
cd "C:\Users\<username>\<folder destination of .jar file>
start javaw -jar <filename.jar>
```

when doubled clicked this will open up the editor.

While this does work, I'd still like to know why this error occurs.